# Does using funcName when logging in Python have any performance impact?

Tags: python, performance, logging

Was just looking at the logging docs in Python and came across funcName as a parameter in the log formatter.

While it looks handy, great way to see exactly where the log is coming from obviously, someone's raised a concern about it, possibly that it would need to generate a stack trace that would be a performance hit.

I assume it uses something like sys._getframe() and not the inspect module, which would have an impact in performance.

Is funcName something we could use in a production environment or should we stay away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resist the temptation to guess, the source for logging is available to you as part of your Python distribution.

How it finds the function name (`logging/__init__.py`):

```
#
# _srcfile is used when walking the stack to check when we've got the first
# caller stack frame.
#
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'): #support for py2exe
    _srcfile = "logging%s__init__%s" % (os.sep, __file__[-4:])
elif __file__[-4:].lower() in ['.pyc', '.pyo']:
    _srcfile = __file__[:-4] + '.py'
else:
    _srcfile = __file__
_srcfile = os.path.normcase(_srcfile)

# next bit filched from 1.5.2's inspect.py
def currentframe():
    """Return the frame object for the caller's stack frame."""
    try:
        raise Exception
    except:
        return sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back

if hasattr(sys, '_getframe'): currentframe = lambda: sys._getframe(3)
# done filching
```

and then later:

```
def findCaller(self):
    """
    Find the stack frame of the caller so that we can note the source
    file name, line number and function name.
    """
    f = currentframe()
    #On some versions of IronPython, currentframe() returns None if
    #IronPython isn't run with -X:Frames.
    if f is not None:
        f = f.f_back
    rv = "(unknown file)", 0, "(unknown function)"
    while hasattr(f, "f_code"):
        co = f.f_code
        filename = os.path.normcase(co.co_filename)
        if filename == _srcfile:
            f = f.f_back
            continue
        rv = (filename, f.f_lineno, co.co_name)
        break
    return rv
```

also, no need to worry about the overhead: it figures out the function name before it works out whether or not you needed it so you might as well use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test app that shows that writing the filename and line number to a file costs around 1sec/500000 requests on my local machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import traceback, sys, time

def writeinfo(f, on=True):

    # give the function something to do
    s=sum(range(1000))

    if on:
        fr = sys._getframe(1)
        s = "%s (line %s) " % (fr.f_code.co_filename, fr.f_lineno)
        f.write(s)

cnt = 50000

t1 = time.time()

f = open('tempfile.log','w')

for i in range(cnt):
    writeinfo(f)

f.close()

t2 = time.time()

for i in range(cnt):
    writeinfo(f, on=False)

t3 = time.time()

print "Test time with    file write: %s" % (t2-t1) 
print "Test time without file write: %s" % (t3-t2)
```

Results:

```
Test time with    file write: 1.17307782173
Test time without file write: 1.08166718483
```